# R ggmap ggplot2 error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

first of all, I apologise.

I know there is numerous threads about this error, however I have tried numerous solutions and I have not managed to get any to solve my issue.

I have tried transforming my data into numerous forms but I still get the same error, or that ggplot2 does not support that data format.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

setwd("~/Projects/reformat")
map <- get_map(location = c(-4,54.5), zoom = 6)
data <- read.csv('lonlatprice.csv')
colnames(data) <- c('Longitude','Latitude','Price')

ggmap(map, extent = "device") + geom_point(aes(x = data$Longitude, y = data$Latitude), colour = "red", 
                                                 alpha = 0.1, size = 2)
```

This is what the data format is like:

```
> head(data)
  Longitude   Latitude  Price
1 53.778274   -2.48129 147500
2 52.833819  -0.936527 182000
3 50.792457   0.046043 193000
4 51.476984  -0.612126 580000
5 51.460139   -0.01867 905000
6 52.235942   1.519404 641500
```

Thanks in advance for help, I have only asked as a last resort after numerous days of no success.

Comment: hi, can you link to questions you have looked, or solutions you have tried that have not helped? That way we can avoid suggesting things which you have already looked through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You retrieved the wrong map. You mixed up the order of the `lon` and `lat` values in `get_map(location = c(-4,54.5), zoom = 6)`
2. You are calling the data in the `geom_point` part in the wrong way.

The following code fixes these problems:

```
map <- get_map(location = c(51.5,0.2), zoom = 6)

ggmap(map) + 
  geom_point(data= data,
             aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),
             colour = "red",
             alpha = 0.5,
             size = 4)
```

and gives you this map:

[image]

Comment: Ahh brilliant, thank you! Such a silly error on my part.